# service applications and/or background modes on tizen samsung tvs

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I've been digging to see if there is any way to have an application run in the background. Looking to fire a request via a push notif or a persistent websocket connection. Their documentation is pretty horrible, so im hoping you fine people at SO have an idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the service application is a part of the native API, and tizen TV at the moment supports only web API apps.